# AngularJS load data (settings) from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, load, application-settings

I've made a simple food-ordering application with Laravel 5. Now I'm trying seperate the front-end and back-end by using AngularJS. Angular grabs it's data from the back-end, which is a REST API based on Laravel (Lumen).

There are a few settings stored in the database which consist of a key-value pair. Think of settings like 'minimum-order-amount' and 'delivery-costs'. Normally I would simply call `setting(key)` within my Laravel application:

```
/**
 * Get the value for the given setting from the database.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $key
 * @return mixed
 */
function setting($key)
{
    static $settings;

    if(is_null($settings)) {
        $settings = Cache::rememberForever('settings', function() {
            return array_pluck(App\Setting::all()->toArray(), 'value', 'key');
        });
    }

    return (is_array($key)) ? array_only($settings, $key) : $settings[$key];
}
```

Notice the static functions which allows me to call the `setting()` function multiple times per request, but only query the database once. How can I achieve this within my Angular application?

I could accomplish the same with something like this:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the value of the given setting.
 */
function setting(key) {
        $.get(apiUrl('api/setting'), function(data) use (key) {
            return data.key;
        });
}
```

...but this would lead to multiple requests (for the same set of data) from the database, multiple times per page load. Which is pretty inefficient.

**Edit (final working example)**

```
app.factory('Setting', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
    var url = 'api/setting';
    var promise = null;

    function load() {
        if ( ! promise) {
            promise = $q.defer();

            $http.get(apiUrl(url))
                .success(function(data) {
                    promise.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    promise.reject(data);
                });
        }

        return promise.promise;
    }

    return {
        load: load
    }
}]);

// Usage
Setting.load().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: angular factories are singletons, so if you wrap your settings in a factory and load it on construction of the factory, it shouldn't be reloading each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a service and if necessary use a cache system.

```
angular.factory('SettingsService', SettingsService);

function SettingsService($q, $http) {
    var userUrl = ApiConfigurationService.userUrl;
    var url = 'api/setting';
    var promise = null;

    function loadSettings() {
        if (!promise) {
           promise = $q.defer();

           $http.get('url', function(res) {
                 settings = res.data;
                 promise.resolve(res.data);
            }, function(res) {promise.reject(res)});
        } 
        return promise.promise;
    }

    return {
         loadSettings: loadSettings
     }
}
```

Then in your controller/directive

```
angular.controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController(SettingsService) {
    var me = this;
    SettingsService.loadSettings(function(res) {
         me.settings = res;});
}
```

Comment: Modified my answer to cache the result

Comment: Thanks alot, definitely helped me the most to get on the right track. Could you point the caching part out? It seems to me that every page request results in a new database query. Also, is there an easier way to grab the settings withing using `var me = this;` and `me.settings = res`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about Laravel, my caching is purely frontend. The caching is done in the service and it prevents different directives/controllers to request multiple time the same resource. You will still need to take care of the caching on the backend. About the settings, it is common practice to access the controller this way. I would advice you to follow

Comment: I got it, thanks :). I've edited the loading function a little to get it working. The last problem I'm facing is that I can't grab the data within my controller.

        `var settings;
        var me = this;

        Setting.load().then(function(result) {
            console.log(result); // works perfect
            me.settings = result;
            settings = null;
        });
        console.log(me.settings + '' + settings); // Both variables are undefined`

Comment: The problem is that you are reading the variable outside the promise. Remember that you are working asyncrhonous. That means that your console.log() will most likely fire before the result from the server has arrived.

Comment: I understand now, so this means I can only use callbacks from within the promise itself. But then, how could I pass these settings on to the scope? I need to do some simple checks with the settings in order to hide and/or show elements on the page.

Comment: you can still do it, Angular will update the page as soon as it gets data. Or simply add some kind of render variable and set to your parent div ng-if="render". render should be set to true as soon as you get ur response.

Comment: You can also look into ng-cloak

Answer (score 2):

You can use angular caching features, described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http ("Caching" section).

It's also possible to implement service for config values, which will load the data once, store it locally and provide getter for stored value.